# more than one item per reference

Tags: biblatex

page 46 of http://pdg.lbl.gov/2012/reviews/rpp2012-rev-standard-model.pdf shows an example of a reference style with more than one item per reference. How can this be mimiced with biblatex?

edit: defbibentryset does the job, but seems to be incompatible with \nocite{*}

Comment: Have a look at section 3.11.5 of the `biblatex` manual, "Entry Sets".

Comment: @Audrey -- I'll admit it: I can't keep up with everything going on in `biblatex`/`biber` ... no matter how hard I try.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This very example can be found in `biblatex-examples.bib` from the biblatex documentation:

```
@set{stdmodel,
  entryset     = {glashow,weinberg,salam},
  annotation   = {A \texttt{set} with three members discussing the standard
                  model of particle physics},
}
```

where the sub-entries `glashow`, `weinberg` and `salam` are later defined as:

```
@article{glashow,
  author       = {Glashow, Sheldon},
  title        = {Partial Symmetries of Weak Interactions},
  journaltitle = {Nucl.~Phys.},
  date         = 1961,
  volume       = 22,
  pages        = {579-588},
}

@article{weinberg,
  author       = {Weinberg, Steven},
  title        = {A Model of Leptons},
  journaltitle = {Phys.~Rev.~Lett.},
  date         = 1967,
  volume       = 19,
  pages        = {1264-1266},
}

@inproceedings{salam,
  author       = {Salam, Abdus},
  editor       = {Svartholm, Nils},
  title        = {Weak and Electromagnetic Interactions},
  date         = 1968,
  booktitle    = {Elementary particle theory},
  booksubtitle = {Relativistic groups and analyticity},
  booktitleaddon= {Proceedings of the Eighth Nobel Symposium},
  eventdate    = {1968-05-19/1968-05-25},
  venue        = {Aspen{\"a}sgarden, Lerum},
  publisher    = {Almquist \& Wiksell},
  location     = {Stockholm},
  pages        = {367-377},
}
```

The entry type `@set` defines the group of references you're after, referred to as an entry set. Entry sets require biber as the backend. The entry `stdmodel` can be cited just like any other entry. Sub-entries can also be cited directly, but for clarity you may wish to enable `subentry` label numbers. Dynamic entry sets can be defined in the document preamble or body with:

```
\defbibentryset{stdmodel:dynamic}{glashow,weinberg,salam}
```

This should both define the entry set `stdmodel:dynamic` and invoke `\nocite{stdmodel:dynamic}`. Sometime after biblatex 1.7, biblatex/biber failed to carry out the implicit `\nocite`. This should be fixed along with some other entry set bugs in biblatex 2.6 and biber 1.6.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric,subentry,firstinits]{biblatex}

\renewcommand{\entrysetpunct}{\par\nobreak}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\defbibentryset{latex}{companion,knuth:ct,ctan}

\begin{document}
Filler text \parencite{stdmodel,latex}. \Textcite{weinberg} showed that...
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that the entry sets are appropriate only for numeric styles. For other styles biblatex and biber offer the more flexible related entries feature. Examples of related entries can also be found in `biblatex-examples.bib`. Details on this feature are available in the biblatex manual and the generic style file `biblatex.def`.